# "For a second" vs. "for the second"

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Could you tell me if the use of *the* but not *a* affect the meaning of the following sentence in any way?

> Could you lay your phone aside and listen to me for **a** second.
>
> Could you lay your phone aside and listen to me for **the** second.

In my experience a is mostly used in similar contexts, but I have also seen *the* used similarly.

Comment: can't imagine the context with "the" can you give a specific example

Comment: If you have, it's non-standard.

Comment: It's *listen **to** me*, not *listen me*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "listen to me for a second", NOT "the second". If you saw an example that said "the second", either the writer made a mistake or you're taking out of context.

This is a classic example of the use of articles "a" vs "the". You're asking the person to  listen for "a second". It is not some particular second, it's any second (presumably within the next few minutes).

Comment: Maybe it was a misreading of "for the second time!".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Yeah, I was thinking the same thing.